# Search for file and display in href for download

Tags: php, jquery, foreach

I am using jQuery and PHP to search for a file in a directory.  If it exists, display it in an `<a>` tag with download feature.

This code works for the most part.  However, I'm experiencing an error which is causing the links to be displayed multiple times.

Starting with JavaScript:

```
$('#submitSearch').on('click', function()
{
  var voyage = $('#voyageText').val();
  $.post('searchVoyages.php', {voyage:voyage}, function(data)
  {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#voyageBody').empty(); 
    var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item)
    {
      return '<tr><td><a href="#" class="voyageFileCall" data-filevoyage="'+item.voyage+'">'+item.voyage+'</a>
      <td>'+item.export_import+'</td></tr>';
    });
    $('#voyageBody').html(htmlToInsert);    

    // The user submits a search, and the data is returned and displayed 
    // in a datatable. (image below) The next part is where the user clicks 
    // the link to open a modal window that display a download link

    $('.voyageFileCall').on('click', function(e)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      var filevoyage = $(this).attr('data-filevoyage');
      $.post('fileDownload.php', {filevoyage:filevoyage}, function(data)
      {
        $('.filelink').empty();
        var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item)
        {
          return '<a href="'+data+'" download>"'+data+'"</a>';
        });
        $('.filelink').html(htmlToInsert);
      });

      $('#downloadFileModal').modal('show');
    });  // end voyageFileCall click
  }); // end searchVoyage post
}); // end submitSearch click
```

After the datatable is displayed, the first column (which is a link) has a class called .voyageFileCall, which upon clicking will take the attribute and post to a process called fileDownload.php.

Here is what fileDownload.php looks like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['filevoyage']))
{
  $voyage = $_POST['filevoyage'];
  $dir = scandir("backup/");
  unset($dir[0], $dir[1]);

  if(count($dir) > 0)
  {
    $fileFound = false;
    foreach($dir as $file)
    {
      if((preg_match("/\b$voyage\b/", $file) === 1))
      {
        $finalLink = 'backup/'.$file;
        echo $finalLink; // I think the problem is in this loop
        $fileFound = true;
      }
    }
    if(!$fileFound) die("File $voyage doesn't exist");
  }
  else
  {
    echo "No files in backup folder";
  }
}
?>
```

So when I'm returning the variable $finalLink, for some reason, it will display the link the same number of times how much data is returned in the datatable.

[image]

But when they click the link, and the window opens, this is what they see:

[image]

In the console, I see this:

[image]

The modal window should open with a single link that the user can click on and download the file from the directory.  But it seems to be displaying the same link however many times the amount of data that was returned from the initial search.

In this case, the initial search returned 7 records.  When the user clicks on the one of the links, the modal opens with 7 links with the same file name.  I can click on each one and it will download my file.  But I only want to display 1 link.

How can I fix my code? I know it has something to do with the foreach loop in the PHP process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a break in your script, under foreach, when it finds the correspondent file that fits your $_POST['filevoyage'] value.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['filevoyage']))
{
  $voyage = $_POST['filevoyage'];
  $dir = scandir("backup/");
  unset($dir[0], $dir[1]);

  if(count($dir) > 0)
  {
    $fileFound = false;
    foreach($dir as $file)
    {
      if((preg_match("/\b$voyage\b/", $file) === 1))
      {
        $finalLink = 'backup/'.$file;
        echo $finalLink; // I think the problem is in this loop
        $fileFound = true;
        break; # *** break here ***
      }
    }
    if(!$fileFound) die("File $voyage doesn't exist");
  }
  else
  {
    echo "No files in backup folder";
  }
}
?>
```

JS part:
Look also at JS. Put off the namespace event added in my script under "click" in `$('#submitSearch')` and `$('.voyageFileCall')` attached events and add a `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` near `event.preventDefault()`. Pass "`e`" or "`event`" (based on your reading preferences) to the called function on "jquery on click".

```
$(document)
.off('click.submitSearch')
.off('click.voyageFileCall')
.on('click.submitSearch', '#submitSearch', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var voyage = $('#voyageText').val();
    $.post('searchVoyages.php', {voyage: voyage}, function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#voyageBody').empty();
        var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item) {
            return '<tr><td><a href="#" class="voyageFileCall" data-filevoyage="' + item.voyage + '">' + item.voyage + '</a><td>' + item.export_import + '</td></tr>';
        });
        $('#voyageBody').html(htmlToInsert);

        // The user submits a search, and the data is returned and displayed
        // in a datatable. (image below) The next part is where the user clicks
        // the link to open a modal window that display a download link
    })
})
.on('click.voyageFileCall', '.voyageFileCall', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var filevoyage = $(this).attr('data-filevoyage');
    $.post('fileDownload.php', {filevoyage: filevoyage}, function (data) {
        $('.filelink').empty();
        var htmlToInsert = '<a href="' + data + '" download>"' + data + '"</a>';
        $('.filelink').html(htmlToInsert);
    });

    $('#downloadFileModal').modal('show');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looked promising, but I still got the same results. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm upvoting your responses for the simple fact that you're taking the time to help me.  However, I am still getting the same results. :(

Comment: Updated. Try, please. Why you are object mapping "obj" under the click call?

Comment: I do believe you have a genius-level intellect.  Thank you, sir.  You helped me solve my problem.  Why am I using "obj"?  Is it not necessary?

Comment: You're welcome. Think mapping its not necessary under the click.voyageFileCall am I right?